# Why the tool-tip pop-up is not appearing when I apply the same logic which is working fine in other fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The non-working fiddle is as follows in which I'm not getting the tool-tip pop-up appear. Also the text to be wrapped inside a tool-tip pop-up is also not hidden:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dq3X7/1/

The working fiddle is as follows in which I'm able to show the tool-tip pop-up on the click of a text contained in . Also the text to be wrapped inside a tool-tip pop-up is also hidden:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3LXR/11/

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<table class="base-table selection-table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                      <tr class="evenRow" id="37261">
              <td class="question">
                <ul class="tabl-head">
                  <li>Question 1.</li>
                  <li class="center-align"><span>Report question issue - QUE37261</span>
                    <ul class="tooltipText">
        <li class='info'>Some text to fill the box with.</li>
          </ul></li>                          

                </ul>                        

               <ul class="options w-auto">   
                                  <li><strong>Question:</strong>
Pair of contrasting characters controlling the same trait is called:

                                  </li> 

                                                         <li><strong>Answer:</strong>
                                            <p>
                                                  <b style="font-size:13px;">1.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
Factors
<br />
                                                 </p>  
                                            <p>
                                                  <b style="font-size:13px;">2.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
alleles
<br />
                                                 </p>  
                                            <p>
                                                  <b style="font-size:13px;">3.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
alloloci
<br />
                                                 </p>  
                                            <p>
                                                  <b style="font-size:13px;">4.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
paramorphs
<br />
                                                 </p>  
                                         </li>
                    <li><strong>Correct Answer Option : 2</strong></li>
                                                 </ul>
                                        </td>
              </tr>
</table>
```

The Javascript of my non-working fiddle(1st one) is as follows:

```
    "use strict";

    function click(event) {
        var elem = this.parentNode.querySelector('.info_container');
        if (elem) 
            elem.style.display = elem.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    function toolify() {
        console.log("toolfiy",arguments)
        var idx,
        len,
        elem,
        info,
        text,
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('li.tooltip'),
            canvas,
            imgurl,
            pointer,
            tipHeight = 20,
            tipWidth = 20,
            width = 200,
            height = 100,
            ctx;

        // Create a canvas element where the triangle will be drawn
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tipHeight;
        canvas.height = tipWidth;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // Border color
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'; // background color
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        ctx.translate(-0.5, -0.5); // Move half pixel to make sharp lines
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(1, canvas.height); // lower left corner

The CSS code for first fiddle is as follows:
li{
   display:block;
}
li.tooltip
{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:300px;
  text-align:right;
}
li.tooltip > ul li.info
{
  display:none;
}
li.tooltip > ul li.info_container
{
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
    color:#000;
}
li.tooltip ul li.info
{
  text-align:left;
  position:absolute;
  left:1px;
  right:1px;
  top:20px;
  bottom:1px;
  color:#000;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

The first fiddle should also work as of second fiddle. That is the tool-tip popup shpuld get appear when user clicks on the text **Report question issue - QUE37261** and also the text to be displayed within a tool tip(i.e. the text "Some text to fill the box with.") should not be displayed initially.

Other similar `<li>s` are also present on the webpage but for your understanding I've put only one entry here. It should work for every entry once it starts working for single entry.

I've applied the same logic as of second fiddle to first one but it's not working. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: Please try to use descriptive titles -- titles that someone would use to search for your issue. I doubt anyone is going to be helped by searching for, "What's wrong with this JSFiddle".

Comment: Your fiddles should be code in your question, not linked to.  If you're able to include a *minimal* working example, it'd be easier to help you and it'd help those that may have a problem similar to yours. As it stands there are two external code dumps and the question is a bit incomplete, so we can't help you solve it without a lot of extra effort on our part.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I've accordingly changed my question and made it more descriptive.

Comment: I got the answer for him. Please re-open the question.

Comment: @PHPGeek The code should be in the question itself, not linked to in a Fiddle (or the Fiddle should be supplementary).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:Now the JavaScript code is also added.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:Now please reopen the question.

Comment: @PHPGeek You have two fiddles listed, one set of JS code, and there's no way to tell which one you've enclosed, and I can't even compile the JS you've included.  

The reason this is like this is so that future visitors can be helped by your question as well.  They can't be helped if the question is incomplete or we just get a code dump.

Comment: Reviewers of the reopen queue, please read comments and look at recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons and solutions to your question.

1) You've used `no wrap - in <head>` for your working fiddle but `onLoad` for your non-working fiddle. The difference between this two is:

- onLoad: wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event
- no wrap - in `<head>`: do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in  section

In your case, you need to use `no wrap - in <head>`

2) You need to add class `tooltip` to the parent `li` of your `.info` li

```
<li class="center-align tooltip"><span>Report question issue - QUE37261</span>
```

3) Add `background-color: #fff;` to your `.info` li to make it cover the content behind it.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq3X7/2/)**